# How to get the exit code from a bash script invoked with winApi CreateProcess?

Tags: bash, winapi, visual-c++, process, cygwin

I'm using CreateProcess to invoke a bash script via Cygwin's bash.exe. The script runs fine, and I'm even able to redirect stdout and stderr to display within my own window. The only problem is that I can't seem to get the bash script's exit code.

Here's how I'm launching the script:

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

STARTUPINFO si; 
si.cb = sizeof (STARTUPINFO); 
si.lpReserved = NULL; 
si.lpDesktop = NULL;
si.lpTitle = NULL; 
si.dwX = 0; 
si.dwY = 0; 
si.dwXSize = 0; 
si.dwYSize = 0; 
si.dwXCountChars = 0; 
si.dwYCountChars = 0; 
si.dwFillAttribute = 0; 
si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW; 
si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE; 
si.cbReserved2 = 0; 
si.lpReserved2 = NULL; 
si.hStdOutput = hChildStdOut;
si.hStdInput  = NULL;
si.hStdError  = hChildStdErr;

CreateProcessW( NULL, 
    L"bash.exe script.sh file_to_process", 
    NULL, 
    NULL, 
    TRUE, 
    CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, 
    NULL, 
    NULL, 
    &si, 
    &pi);

hChildProcess = pi.hProcess;
```

And here is how I'm attempting to get the exit code:

```
WaitForSingleObject(hChildProcess, 0);
DWORD exitCode = 999;
GetExitCodeProcess(hChildProcess, &exitCode);
DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
```

Both exitCode and lastError seem to always be zero regardless of the exit code that should have been returned by the script.

**Update**

As cwgem pointed out, the script was using `exit` to exit the script. I tried changing them all to `return`, which exitCode = 1, which is not a value returned by the script. A bit of Googling got me `$(exit n)`, which sort of works, but I only get the final exit code from the script (currently 7 for testing, but would normally be 0).

So, for example, I have the following block in my script:

```
if [ `/cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/find $root -name '*.xml' | grep -c .xml` -eq 0 ] ; then
echo No XMLs present in $root!
$(exit 2)
fi
```

When I test this path I get the "No XMLs" message in stdout, as expected, but I don't get 2 as my exit code. Instead I get 7, which as I noted above is the final exit statement in the script.

I can create a variable to store my exitcode and return that at the end, but that doesn't feel like the correct solution since I'd potentially be executing code that I shouldn't.

I should perhaps note that I'm neither the author nor the maintainer of the script, I've just been asked to run it from my application.

Answer (score 2):

You should check your script's execution flow, as bash will return as the exit code the return value of the last run command unless you:

- Exit forcefully using `exit [returncode]`
- `set -e` at the beginning of the script, which will exit immediately when any command exits with a non-zero value

Comment: The script is using `exit`, but that's only given me a partial solution. I'll update the question.